# Disabling the running-twice with Zeus in Rails 4 minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, minitest, zeus

Zeus has a known issue where it runs specs double if you include the default "autorunner" for a testing suite.

> It is common to see tests running twice when starting out with Zeus.
>   If you see your tests/specs running twice, you should try disabling
>   require 'rspec/autotest' and require 'rspec/autorun' (for RSpec), or
>   require 'minitest/autorun' (for Minitest). (see #134 for more
>   information).
>      https://github.com/burke/zeus#important

However, Rails4 minitest includes "rails/test_help" which is a file in Railties 4.0.0; which includes yet another custom runner. And does other generic of setup and configuration.

For Rails4 with default minitest, there is no simple include to leave out, it seems.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was just facing this same problem with Rails4+minitest+zeus.
After i include `gem "minitest-rails-shoulda"` in my Gemfile, zeus starts to run tests twice.

I just changed the gem orders at Gemfile and it solves!

**Gemfile with Zeus running twice:**

```
group :test do
    gem "minitest-rails-shoulda"
    gem 'minitest'
    #...
end
```

**Gemfile CORRECT:**

```
group :test do
    gem 'minitest'
    gem "minitest-rails-shoulda"
    #....
end
```